# CSS absolute positioning issue: Child element overflowing parent with 'overflow: auto'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container with overflow: auto and a child element positioned absolutely inside it. The child element (left-popup) is intended to be partially visible within the container. However, it seems to be overflowing the container, and I'm unable to see the entire left-popup element.

```html
<div class="container" style="height: 200px; overflow: auto; margin-left: 100px;">
  <div class="popup-container" style="height: 300px; background: #ccc; position: relative;">
    <div class="left-popup" style="position: absolute; height: 100px; width: 50px; background: #9C27B0; left: 0;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Actual Behavior:

The left-popup element overflows the popup-container, and I'm unable to see the entire element.

I want the left-popup element to be partially visible within the popup-container while still maintaining the overflow property of the container.

Comment: No part of the `.left-popup` element is overflowing the container, so I'm confused as to what you think the issue is, and what you're expecting to see

Comment: Also, CSS styling should be held within a separate stylesheet and not placed inline in the HTML

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean? Your question is very confusing

Putting the CSS styles in a stylesheet will make your code look better

```css
.container {
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: 100px;
}
.popup-container {
height: 300px;
background: #ccc;
position: relative;
}
.left-popup {
position: absolute;
height: 100px; 
width: 50px;
background: #9C27B0;
left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="popup-container">
    <div class="left-popup"></div>
  </div>
</div
```